# lacunary series with Jensen's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma_{n}\in \mathbb R$ such that $\gamma=\liminf_{|n|\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\lambda_{n}}{n}>0$. We suppose that $\sum_{n}|c_{n}|<\infty$ and $f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_{n}e^{i\lambda_{n}t}$ ; $t\in\mathbb R$. I have to show that if $f=0$ on any interval of length > $2\pi/\gamma$, then $f\equiv 0$.
I have tried to use this relation $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-tz}dt=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{c_{n}}{z-i\lambda_{n}}$; $Re z>0$ along with the Jensen's formula applied on $H(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{c_{n}}{z-i\lambda_{n}}$ but i am stuck at this level. Thank you for any help.